# org.apache.struts2.json.annotations.JSON doesn't show right format

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

My web application uses `struts2-json-plugin-2.2.1`

I have an action that exposes an object loaded from DB (through hibernate).

This object contain a java.util.Date field that is so annotated:

```
  @JSON(format = "dd-MM-yyyy")
  @Column(name = "DATA_CREAZIONE", nullable = false)
  public Date getDataCreazione() {
    return this.dataCreazione;
  }
```

Instead of getting:

```
"dataCreazione":"15-02-2013"
```

I get this:

```
"dataCreazione":"2013-02-15T16:51:06"
```

In debug I notice that the `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter` class doesn't find any annotation over the `getDataCreazione` method and that the *proxy* class is of the `"$$_javassist"` type rather than `"$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$"` as other cases...

In the same application I have a lot of this situations and the annotation works fine.
I don't understand what is the problem (or the difference) with other classes.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: btw I confirm the origin of my problem.

As I said before it resides in the proxy class that are used.

In my case

- if I **load** the object (through hibernate) then the proxy used is $$_javassist

- if I **get** the object (through hibernate) then the object isn't proxied  and then JSonWriter can resume the annotation -> so it's able to format as I have annotated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw I confirm the origin of my problem. As I said before it resides in the proxy class that are used. In my case - if I **load** the object (through hibernate) then the proxy used is $$_javassist - if I **get** the object (through hibernate) then the object isn't proxied and then JSonWriter can resume the annotation -> so it's able to format as I have annotated –

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify `name` of the annotation attribute. By default annotations with empty names are not deserialized. For further references take a look at the [Apache docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-CustomizingSerializationandDeserialization).

Comment: For sure, by default, the plugin deserialize every field with its own name.
The tag "name" that you mentioned is used to rename the specific field name.

For example:
 `@JSON(name="newName4Field2")
  public String getField2() {
    return field2;
  }`

will generate this

`{"field1":"FIELD_1","newName4Field2":"FIELD_2","testDate":"05-03-2013"}`